# Difference between a Factory, Provider and a Service?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, repository-pattern

What is the difference between the terms Factory, Provider and Service?

Just getting into NHibernate and its Repository pattern (POCO classes, etc).

Answer (score 228):

**Factory**: Assembles classes, either by composing a bunch of bits together, or choosing type based on some kind of context

**Provider**: Provider is something microsoft "invented" (basically an abstract factory pattern) that is a way of doing a factory of factories, or having a common factory interface which allows factories to be swappable. It is used all over in the MS web stack as a way to keep components configurable.

**Service**: A service is a group of related functionality. Think of it as if you are splitting your architecture horizontally, you have a "Business Logic" layer, if you split that vertically you will have services.

Comment: A service can also have the notion of having no state.. it operates on other objects to do its services, without having a state on its own. At least in Domain Driven Design.

Comment: is the Factory will be generated instance in Angular like Service or just use the static method ?

Comment: @qianjiahao a general recommendation is to avoid static methods.

Comment: MS comes up frequently with their use of a provider pattern but I'm not sure there's grounds to say they invented it. It also [appears in React](https://mortenbarklund.com/blog/react-architecture-provider-pattern/) and others [identify it's source elsewhere](https://mortenbarklund.com/blog/react-architecture-provider-pattern/) too.