# Data Provider or Factory

Tags: c#, asp.net, design-patterns, architecture

I often get confused with the design term `provider` and `factory`. Below is my code to choose a different database context based on the name supplied. I have used a factory pattern here, so i name it as `DataContextFactory`. Is this correct for this approach? Or do i need to change it to DataContextProvider? will this mean something different implementation?

```
public class DataContextFactory
{
    public static DataContext GetDataContext(string databaseName)
    {
        switch (databaseName.ToLower())
        {
            case "app":
                return new ApplicationDataContext();
            case "customer":
                return new CustomerDataContext();
            default:
                return new TestDataContext();
        }
    }
}
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1849645/1559213 this one confused me

Answer (score 3):

Imho, in general - Provider "provides" any functionality (usually highly specialized) except creation/building object e.g. DataProvider or SecurityProvider. For creation/building there are separated abstractions(patterns) like Factory/FactoryMethod/Builder etc...

Comment: Double. So in this case it is factory as it creates actually what is a provider (the repository).

Answer (score 2):

In general, I'd say it doesn't matter. More important is that your naming is consistent.

If you name it `Provider` it's still a Factory-pattern. A Factory pattern does not necessarily mean you need to suffix it with Factory, it's jsut how you choose to name things, as long as it's obvious to the user of your code what it is doing you're fine

Comment: Nothing to confuse. What you have up there is a factory.... and the DataContext ist then a provider.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents: depends on what you'd like to get, if you want to get data, then create a data provider, if you want the context you can use a context factory. More likely you'll end up using both. You can inject the context in your data provider which uses the context to bring you data.