# Is there a difference between .service() and .factory() provider calls in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1849618/difference-between-a-factory-provider-and-a-service) (and numerous others) point out that .factory and .service are distinct convenience functions over the provider() functionality.

However, I don't see any distinction between a .service() and a .factory() call (ie: the tests below pass). Can someone help me understand what I'm missing. thanks

```
angular.module('myMod', [])
  .service('myService', function() {
    return function() {return 33};
  })
  .factory('myFactory', function() {
    return function() {return 33};
  });

describe('my app tests', function() {

  beforeEach(module('myMod'));

  it('services should work', inject(function(myService) {
    expect(myService()).to.equal(33);
  }));

  it('factories should work', inject(function(myFactory) {
    expect(myFactory()).to.equal(33);
  }));

});
```

Comment: It seems that you can either return a factory function, or a new-able function.. but what I'm trying to get at is: there doesn't seem to be any real difference between how a .service() call works, vs a .factory() call.

Comment: agreed. I'll remove the close vote

Comment: on another note, an extreme take on this issue: http://codeofrob.com/entries/you-have-ruined-javascript.html

Comment: This blogger seem to have misunderstood the use of `.service`, `.factory`, and `.provider`. It's one or the other, not all of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.factory` is used to register a function that returns an instance of an object that will be the injected service singleton.

`.service` is used to register a function that will be used as constructor of an object that will be the injected service singleton.

`.service` actually uses `.factory` under the covers. From [src](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.3.14/src/auto/injector.js#L692):

```
function service(name, constructor) {
  return factory(name, ['$injector', function($injector) {
    return $injector.instantiate(constructor);
  }]);
}
```

In other words, `.service` registers a factory function that calls `$injector.instantiate` on the function (called `constructor` above) that is registered with `.service`.

Now, to your case, the function you register is:

```
var fn = function(){ return function(){ return 13; }; }
```

`fn` just returns an object (which happens to be another function).

In `.factory` case, `fn` is invoked directly: `var svc = fn();`

In `.service` case, `fn` is called like a constructor, but ends up not setting anything on `this` and returning an object (constructors can return a different instance than `this`) - same function object as above. So, `var svc = $injector.instantiate(fn)`.

In both cases, `svc` equals to a function object: `function(){ return 13; }`

Comment: Here is my understanding this far:

 * You can inject a service in many places; each is the same instance.
A service is not parameterizable.

 * A factory is parameterizable, and designed to create multiple instances; Controller providers are examples of a factory. You have to use new X() when using a factory.